# Reduce list of lists in JAX

Tags: python, jax

I have a list holding many lists of the same structure (Usually, there are much more than two sub-lists inside the list, the example shows two lists for the sake of simplicity). I would like to create the sum or product over all sub-lists so that the resulting list has the same structure as one of the sub-lists. So far I tried the following using the `tree_reduce` method but I get errors that I don't understand.

I could need some guidance on how to use tree_reduce() in such a case.

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

list_1 = [
    [jnp.asarray([1]), jnp.asarray([2, 3])],
    [jnp.asarray([4]), jnp.asarray([5, 6])],
]

list_2 = [
    [jnp.asarray([7]), jnp.asarray([8, 9])],
    [jnp.asarray([10]), jnp.asarray([11, 12])],
]
    
list_of_lists = [list_1, list_2]
   
reduced = jax.tree_util.tree_reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, list_of_lists, 0, is_leaf=True)
    
# Expected
# reduced = [
#     [jnp.asarray([8]), jnp.asarray([10, 12])],
#     [jnp.asarray([14]), jnp.asarray([16, 18])],
# ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `tree_map` of a `sum` over the splatted list:

```py
reduced = jax.tree_util.tree_map(lambda *args: sum(args), *list_of_lists)
print(reduced)
```

```
[[Array([8], dtype=int32), Array([10, 12], dtype=int32)],
 [Array([14], dtype=int32), Array([16, 18], dtype=int32)]]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I spent way too much time on this. Why can't I replace `sum` by `jax.numpy.sum` in this case? I also tried `tree, *rest = list_of_lists` and `jax.tree_map(jnp.sum, tree, *rest)`? This works for two lists, but stops working for more than that.

Comment: And why can't I use `tree_reduce` in such a case? The method's name sound intuitively like the right candidate for such an operation. Could you please add a hint how I can weight each list using a list of weights `weights = [1, 2, 3]`? Can I still use `tree_map` for a weighted sum?

Comment: `tree_reduce` applies a reduction over the leaves of a single tree. Your desired result is not a reduction over the leaves of a single tree, but rather a sum mapped over the leaves of a sequence of trees. Regarding `weights`: it is possible to do, but multi-line code in not allowed in comments, so it would be better to ask this new question in a new post.